# Delphi XE7 MultiDevice SQL Error TIMESTAMP Ret. Field

Tags: mysql, sql-server, delphi

I've an `SQLTIMESTAMP` binded (SQL output of query from datamodule)

> (On live bindings) -> BindVIsually TTMFSMXGRID.

When I open the query, the field is correctly filled in the grid (EX: `06/05/2016`, etc)

But when I try to take the `Cell[x,y]` as `StringToSqltimestamp` it come back in a different format (`WRONG FORMAT`). And I am trying to use field for a query so it make me an error (`EOF`) because don't find anything in that date.

```
dm1.UpdMsg.ParamByName('data').AsSQLTimeStamp:=StrToSQLTimeStamp(GrRec.Cells[1,GrRec.FocusedCell.Row]);
```

Any idea about how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other date/time formatting functions, [`StrToSqlTimeStamp()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlTimSt.StrToSQLTimeStamp) by default uses formatting criteria based on the current system locale.  If that does not match what you need (for example, maybe the day and month are swapped), you can use the overloaded version that accepts a [`TFormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) as input so you can customize it.

```
var
  Fmt: TFormatSettings;
begin
  // Get default settings first...
  Fmt := TFormatSettings.Create;

  // customize Fmt as needed...
  Fmt.ShortDateFormat := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
  Fmt.DateSeparator := '/';

  // not convert...
  dm1.UpdMsg.ParamByName('data').AsSQLTimeStamp := StrToSQLTimeStamp(GrRec.Cells[1,GrRec.FocusedCell.Row], Fmt);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but , what do you mean for '' // customize Fmt as needed...''?
Past string //--//--//
New String// - // - //? Like a String Function as (Replace/Copy/Mod)?

Comment: Thanks a lot , i will try it As soon as Possible. Thanks !

Comment: It don't work , cuz the problem it's about the last 3 digit after date and time

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: thanks , at first i don't make it works but now it work as well